# What is wrong with this code (responsive html-css-js)?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xibalbian/qbq8S/embedded/result/ 
What I want to achieve send that aside to right without breaking responsive video.

```
<section id="full-video">
    <div class="video-wrapper">
        <div class="video-container">
            <iframe width="640" height="480" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/WeYsTmIzjkw?rel=0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<aside id="social" class="margin2">
   <a href="www.example.com" class="indiegogo" data-lang="en"><img src="img/indie.png" style='width:auto; max-width:200px;' border="0"></a>
   <a href="www.facebook.com/examplepage" class="fbgroup" data-lang="en"><img src="img/fbgroup.png" style='width:auto; max-width:200px;'></a>
   <div class="twitter-follow-button"><a href="https://twitter.com/arterast" class="twitter-follow-button" data-show-count="false" data-lang="en">Follow</a></div>
   <div class="fb-like" data-href="https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/" data-layout="button_count" data-action="like" data-show-faces="true" data-share="true"></div>
   <div class="twitter-share-button"><a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-lang="en">Tweet</a></div>
   <div class="g-plusone"></div>
</aside>
```

The layout is okay, aside is on the right. But the video is not responsive.

When I change `<section id="full-video">` to `<section id="full-video margin">`

(here is the fiddle for that: http://jsfiddle.net/xibalbian/72wG5/#base) ...the video acts responsive but then that aside goes under the video...
The code is not so well but I am trying to improve myself, sorry about that.
What am I missing?

Comment: If, by "responsive," you mean that the video size should change based on the browser window size, you're going to have a hard time doing that when you fix the containing `<iframe>` dimensions to 640 x 480. Nothing you do in CSS can override your inline fixed dimensions.

Comment: I know, before I tried `style="display:inline-block; width:100%; min-height: 550px;"` without margin but then still there was a problem about size. Now, the size is adaptive but there is a problem with that aside, I couldn't spot it. Can you make a fiddle to show a way out for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `<section id="full-video">` to `<section class="full-video">`

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qbq8S/1/

**EDIT**
Changed CSS on some of the children in section.

Final Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qbq8S/5/

Comment: Done, but still couldn't made aside is not at the right of the video

Comment: Hm, let me take a look.

Comment: Yes. Here you go. http://jsfiddle.net/qbq8S/5/ The child in the section was a  block and took up the whole line. I changed some css on that.